# No such DSL method 'getVar' while using shared libraries

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have created a shared library to hold my declarative pipeline and then calling it in Jenkinsfile. In Jenkins file there are definitions for for methods that are invoked in the pipeline scripts in the shared library. I don't understand why this error occur. 
What is a solution for this?

**Jenkinsfile:**

```
@Library('jenkinsLib')_

def getVar(){
   echo "${env.myVar}"
}

mymaster()
```

Under var in **jenkinsLib** shared library a script **mymaster.groovy**:

```
def call(){

  pipeline {
      agent any
      stages {
        stage('one') {
          steps {
            echo "This is Pipeline one"
            getVar()
          }
        }
      }
    }

}
```

It can work when the functions are defined with the pipeline definition which opposes DRY and make pipelines look big and repeated. Below shows this case:

```
def call(){

  pipeline {
      agent any
      stages {
        stage('one') {
          steps {
            echo "This is Pipeline one"
            getVar()
          }
        }
      }
    }

} 

def getVar(){
   echo "${env.myVar}"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's optimal solution, I'm a Jenkins Pipeline and Groovy newbie, but this worked for me.

Here's `Jenkinsfile`:

```java
@Library('jenkinsLib') _

def getVar() {
  echo "${env.myVar}"
}

mymaster(this.&getVar)
```

And here's `mymaster.groovy`:

```java
def call(Closure getVar) {
  pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
      stage('one') {
        steps {
          echo "This is Pipeline one"
          script {
            getVar()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Summary:** you may pass method (closure) as a parameter to make it visible inside of `call()` method. To get closure you need to use `.&` operator. Also, Jenkins complains about calling methods outside of `script` clause, so you may need to add one.

As a side note I'd like to mention that such approach is very clear (explicit) - inside of library you are using only what you know and code doesn't have external dependencies.

If you want to pass many methods as arguments you may consider using `Map` to catch many arguments and to allow more explicit calling.

Modified `Jenkinsfile` with more methods and new call style:

```java
@Library('jenkinsLib') _

def getVar(){
  echo "${env.myVar}"
}

def getVar2(){
  echo "${env.myVar2}"
}

mymaster([
  getVar: this.&getVar,
  getVar2: this.&getVar2
])
```

And `mymaster.groovy` using `Map` in place of fixed arguments:

```java
def call(Map args) {
  pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
      stage('one') {
        steps {
          echo "This is Pipeline one"
          script {
            args.getVar()
            args.getVar2()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, there's a drawback in this solution - you don't have as much control over passed arguments, you need to check manually what is in `args` map (or don't make mistakes in arguments while calling).

Comment: Clever workaround to use a reference argument like that for a method defined above the invoked method's scope. Ideally the method in the question should be within or parallel in scope though.

Comment: I think it's not possible (same scope) because @Badr wants to have something like a framework - glue logic defined in library, but actual work located in job itself.

Comment: This is what i have already done actually. I just didn’t like it since I have many methods.

Comment: I think explicit is better than implicit. To reduce the burden of creating many method arguments you may use `def call(Map args)` and then call functions like `args.fun1()`. This way you can write method call in more descriptive way: `mymaster([fun1: this.&fun1])`.

Comment: @Tupteq I think this makes this solution more neat. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt Schuchard Thank you for the suggestion but since  I have many pipelines that are using the same methods it would be just redundant and makes scripts bigger. I have mentioned this in the question.

Comment: @Tupteq Your comment is what I was suggesting to fix the scope issue instead of working around it.

Comment: @Badr See Tupteq comment above for further explanation around how to improve the architecture to avoid the scope issue. Moving methods out of your `Jenkinsfile` and into the global vars will help with your code organization and maintenance.

Comment: @Badr Updated solution. Maybe someone will have use of it. Also added note about drawback of `Map` based solution.

Comment: If Jenkins would provide more recent Groovy version, we wouldn't have to live with the drawbacks of `Map` based solution. Since Groovy 2.5 there is [`@NamedVariant Annotation`](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2018/06/groovy-goodness-creating-extra-method.html) which automatically converts positional parameters into named parameters, while providing type safety. Unfortunately Jenkins still uses Groovy 2.4 :-(

Answer (score 0):

Any Groovy code must be used within a `script` section. Only Jenkins' methods can be used without `script` (i.e. just with `steps`).

In your case,

```
def getVar(){
   echo "${env.myVar}"
}
```

is a Groovy function, so you need to use it inside a `script` section.

Comment: Actually you *can* define functions outside of `pipeline` and use them as steps even without a `script` section. [Try this!](https://gist.github.com/zett42/5961bc1e9f6a19c38ff7a92145ea6318)

Comment: @zett42 for some reason this doesn't work if function is passed to library. It yields error: `Method calls on objects not allowed outside "script" blocks.`.

Comment: @Tupteq This is normal restriction of declarative pipeline, you can only call global functions or classes that define a `call` method outside `script` blocks.